# 3D Ploting in Scilab: Weird plot behaviour

Tags: plot, scilab

I want to plot a function in scilab in order to find the maximum over a range of numbers:

```
function y=pr(a,b)
  m=1/(1/270000+1/a);
  n=1/(1/150000+1/a);
  y=5*(b/(n+b)-b/(m+b))
endfunction

x=linspace(10,80000,50)
y=linspace(10,200000,50)
z=feval(x,y,pr)
surf(x,y,z);
disp( max(z))
```

For these values this is the plot:

[image]

It's obvious that **increasing the `X axis` will not increase the maximum** but `Y axis` will.
However from my tests it seems the two axis are mixed up. Increasing the `X axis` will actually double the max `Z value`.

**For example**, this is what happens when I increase the `Y axis` by a factor of ten (which intuitively **should increase the function value**):

[image]

It seems to increase the other axis (in the sense that `z vector` is calculated for `y,x` pair of numbers instead of `x,y`)!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephane's answer is correct, but I thought I'd try to explain better why / what is happening.

From the `help surf` page (emphasis mine):

> X,Y:
> two vectors of real numbers, of lengths nx and ny ; or two real matrices of sizes ny x nx: They define the data grid (horizontal coordinates of the grid nodes). All grid cells are quadrangular but not necessarily rectangular. **By default, X = 1:size(Z,2) and Y = 1:size(Z,1)** are used.
>
> Z:
> a real matrix explicitly defining the heights of nodes, of sizes **n<sub>y</sub>  x n<sub>x</sub>**.

In other words, think of surf as `surf( Col, Row, Z )`

From the `help feval` page (changed notation for convenience):

> z=feval(u,v,f):
> returns the matrix z such as z(i,j)=f(u(i),v(j))

In other words, in your `z` output, the `i` become rows (and therefore `u` should represent your *rows*), and `j` becomes your columns (and therefore `v` should represent your *columns*).

Therefore, you can see that you've called `feval` with the `x`, `y` arguments the other way round. In a sense, you should have designed `pr` so that it should have expected to be called as pr(y,x) instead, so that when passed to `feval` as `feval(y,x,pr)`, you would end up with an output whose rows increase with `y`, and columns increase with `x`.

Then you could have called `surf(x, y, z)` normally, knowing that `x` corresponds to columns, and `y` corresponds to rows.

However, if you don't want to change your whole function just for this, which presumably you don't want to, then you simply have to transpose z in the call to surf, to ensure that you match x to the columns or `z'` (i.e, the rows of `z`), and y to the rows of `z'` (i.e. the columns of `z`).

Having said all that, it would probably be much better to make your function *vectorized*, and just use the `surf(x, y, pr)` syntax directly.

Comment: Yeah, this is the Matlab convention, i.e. when you look at the z matrix on a cartesian system, rows correspond to ordinates and columns to abscisae.

Answer (score 2):

With Scilab's surf you have to use transposed z if comming from feval. It is easy so realize if you use a different number of points in X and Y directions, as surf will complain about the size of the third argument. So in your case, use:

```
surf(x,y,z')
```

For more information see the help page of surf.